# Capistrano deployment failing on assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, capistrano3

I have been using capistrano 3 for my rails app for sometime. Today it started failing at assets precompilation step with the following on logs that aren't very helpful:

On the server I have

1. node 10.12.0
2. yarn 1.10.1
3. rails 5.1.6
4. ruby 2.5.1
5. rbenv 1.1.1

---

```
Caused by:
PrecompileRequired: PrecompileRequired


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: ls exit status: 2
ls stdout: ls: cannot access '/var/www/bubblin.io/releases/20181020142819/assets_manifest_backup': No such file or directory
ls stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as marvin@bubblin.io: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
rake aborted!
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v5.4.1. Update it.
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.2.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:163:in `runtime'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.2.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:37:in `process'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.2.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails/sprockets.rb:20:in `run'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.2.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails/sprockets.rb:14:in `call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:99:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:129:in `depend_on_asset'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:160:in `link_asset'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:27:in `compute_asset_path'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:198:in `asset_path'
/var/www/bubblin.io/releases/20181020145802/app/assets/javascripts/serviceworkers/sw.js.erb:60:in `_evaluate_template'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/erb_processor.rb:26:in `call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/erb_processor.rb:13:in `call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/marvin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/marvin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'

/var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'

/var/w

 DEBUG [709144dc]   ww/bubblin.io/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

/home/marvin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'

/home/marvin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Edit: My `yarn.lock` file looks like so:

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1
```

Actually, I don't use yarn for anything--was putting up with it because Rails decided to use it by default. I'll be happy we can remove it forever and have the error above be gone with it.

Comment: Have you checked `node version` in `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: There isn't a node version on `yarn.lock`.  Actually, I don't need yarn per se so it might as well make sense to remove it from the app completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't have yarn installed in your deployment server. Did you already installed it? If not, try this command before a new deploy:

`npm install yarn -g`

Comment: Yarn is already installed with $ brew install yarn on production server.